# conversion of assembly

Tags: assembly

can somebody please explain is it possible to convert this snippet of the code to assembly of pdp11?

```
movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -12(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -16(%rbp)
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rdi
    movq    -8(%rbp), %r8
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rcx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rdx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rdx,%rax), %eax
    addl    (%rcx,%rsi), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%rdi,%r8)
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rdi
    movq    -8(%rbp), %r8
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rcx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rdx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rdx,%rax), %edx
    movl    (%rcx,%rsi), %eax
    subl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%rdi,%r8)
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rdi
    movq    -8(%rbp), %r8
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rcx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rdx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rdx,%rax), %edx
    movl    (%rcx,%rsi), %eax
    subl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%rdi,%r8)
    leave
    ret
```

it is only small part of all code that I have...
also I has C code of the same program, I found that using gcc -S flag, I can get assembly code but can I convert it to the code of pdp11?

Comment: no, I have only simulator, is it possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible -- I can't imagine why you'd want to

Comment: Because the PDP-11 is awesome?

Comment: To let the compiler do homework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get you right you just want to run a C program. If that's right, you can see here that PDP-11 is supported by GCC 4.3.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection#Architectures

Get GCC 4.3 sources, learn how to build a cross-compiler and your problem is solved.

No need to translate amd64 assembly to PDP-11

Comment: can You explain please about cross-compiler, I'm not sure that I understood it

Comment: @lego69 A Cross-compiler is a compiler that runs on a different architecture than the code it will compile. If you search for gcc building a cross-compiler you will get all you need. In unix you would do ./configure --target=pdp11 or something of the sort in GCC source directory and then make. If you want a binary instead of just assembly output you will also need a cross-* version of `binutils` also made by GNU. If you are in Windows it might be more difficult, I recommend getting cygwin as the easiest way out because you can use the same commands you will find on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the PDP-11 is a 16-bit processor, you'd be much better off running your C through a compiler that will produce 16-bit code instead of the 64-bit code you've posted. It's probably easier to translate from C source code to assembly (by hand) than from 64-bit Intel assembly to PDP-11 assembly by hand.

You might also want to look at Dennis Ritchie's [primeval C compilers](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/primevalC.html) page. As I recall, he has a link to somebody who's gotten one or two of these old compilers to compile and run in modern C. Its targets the PDP-11 (though the source it accepts is NOT modern C). You might also look at the work that's been done on targeting the [PDP-11 with lcc](http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/info/lcc-pdp11.html). I believe there's a complete, working implementation. Though I have no idea whether anybody has tested it recently, somewhere in the [pcc](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/) archives, there should probably still be an ancient PDP-11 code generator (that was heavily used at one time).

Comment: @Jerroy Coffin: sorry but what about gcc, it will be easier? or not?

Comment: @lego69: maybe. Until you try, there probably is no other answer (different people clearly find different things easier).

Comment: @Jerroy Coffin: can I do just something like this gcc -pdp-11 -S foo.c?

Comment: @lego69, no, but you can do something like pdp11-gcc -S foo.c if you use a cross-compiler.